# IPFS file download

Tags: ipfs

I wanted to check that is there any way i can download the IPFS file without running the local demon. I am working on a Dapp where i will be uploading the files over IPFS and sending the link of it to the respective team.  I want that team to download the file.

Comment: You can use Infura's IPFS service

Comment: Can you please send me this full project code, because am doing something similar to this

Answer (score 2):

You can add the npm library 'ipfs' in your DApp.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipfs

**lib/ipfs.js**

```
const IPFS = require('ipfs');
const node = new IPFS();

 /**
 * Function that uploads file onto IPFS
 * @param {JSON} fileDetails Json containing file details that needs to be 
   updated on IPFS
 * @param {function} callback callback function
 */
const uploadFileToIPFS = function(fileDetails, callback) {
    let fileContent = fs.readFileSync(fileDetails.path);
    node.files.add({
        path: fileDetails.originalname,
        content: fileContent
    }, (err, filesAdded) => {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }
        callback(null, {
            hash: filesAdded[0].hash
        });
    });
};


/**
 * Function that gets the document contents from IPFS, based on the document's hash
 * @param {String} ipfsHash IPFS hash of the document that is being uploaded onto IPFS
 * @param {function} callback callback function
 */
const getFileContentsFromIPFS = function(ipfsHash, callback) {
    node.files.cat(ipfsHash, function(err, data) {
        callback(err, data);
    });
};
```

**routes/ipfs.js**

```
// API that gets the documents from IPFS
router.get('/api/to/get/document/from/ipfs', function(req, res){
    ipfs.getFileContentsFromIPFS(req.query.ipfsHash, function(err, result){
        if (err) {
            res.json({
                status: 'error',
                message: 'Something went wrong while fetching document from IPFS'
            });
        } else {
            //Get the file type
            let isImageOrPdf = fileType(result);
            if (isImageOrPdf.ext == 'pdf') {
                res.writeHead(200,{
                    'Content-type': 'application/pdf'
                });
                res.end(result);
            } else if(isImageOrPdf.ext == 'png' || isImageOrPdf.ext == 'jpg' ){
                res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'image/png'});
                res.end(result);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And instead of sending the link, send the ipfsHash of the document and whenever they want to download the file, get the ipfsHash and hit the aboove API and that file will be downloaded.

Comment: Hi...what is ipfs.getFileContentsFromIPFS.  I am getting error as ipfs is not declared.

Comment: You have to require lib/ipfs.js file in routes/ipfs.js, then you will not get the error.
In routes/ipfs.js
const ipfs = require(''/path/to/lib/ipfs.js);

Comment: ok...thanks.  Now i am wondering how do we get the file back in its original form.  I mean "result" is not in the same format which i uploaded.  I am getting result but how do i convert it in its original format.  Looks like i am missing something.. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The res object in getFileContentFromIpfs will get the file in its original format depending on the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try http gateway[Cloudflare IPFS gateway - IPFS news](https://ipfsdrop.com/en/docs/cloudflare-ipfs-gateway/)